# Would you consider Numb3rs to be science fiction rather than math fiction?

Tags: tv

I haven't watched many episodes of that show. But from what little I've seen, they seem to be dealing more with scientific concepts than with mathematical concepts, like the episode in which they calculated bullet trajectories to catch a serial killer.

Comment: This question would be better suited to [the meta side of this site](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/), if anywhere, because it invites discussion and is definitionally opinion-based.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about genre classification, which is off-topic per the site FAQ.

Comment: @Keen That went over much better than it would have on math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 4):

Science Fiction implies something very different than "fiction about science".

> **Science Fiction** refers specifically to a genre of fiction dealing with imaginative content such as futuristic settings, futuristic science and technology, space travel, time travel, faster than light travel, parallel universes, and extraterrestrial life. It often explores the potential consequences of scientific and other innovations, and has been called a "literature of ideas".

So, **NO**, Numb3rs is not **science fiction**. What it is, is a crime drama / police procedural with focus on a scientific consultant - a crime drama with a science gimmick, one could say.